# Invalidate Session and Logout from WebSeal

Tags: session, jsf, websphere, single-sign-on, webseal

In WebSeal, there's a junction configured for a web application. Obviously, when the context is called (/app), the Login popup of WebSeal is invoked, and the user provides the username and the password.

The application receives from WebSeal's request a header that I use in order to retrieve the username and login to the user.

Now the point is that I need to logout, I am destroying the session, however WebSeal's "session" (let's say it that way) remains alive, so if I invoke the context again (/app), I never receive the popup again, the header with the username is already there.

I'm invalidating the session using:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
```

Is there any known idea on how I should force the browser to re-invoke WebSeal's login popup?

Comment: show `javax.faces.event.PhaseListener`

Comment: @Abihabi87 can you please explain more what you need? To implement the Phase Listener?

Comment: To logout from webseal you have to call `/pkmslogout`.  See [Webseal Logout](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSP4XS_2.1.0/com.ibm.icip.doc/eai_integration/r_eai_webseal_logout.html). So redirect to that url after you invalidate application session.

Comment: @Gas, your comment should be an answer!